# Does my single-entry Schengen visa let me travel between France and Italy?

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas

I got the 'Etats Schengen' visa from the Frence Embassy, single entry type C visa. I understand that having a Etats Schengen visa means I can travel to all Schengen countries.

I am planning to go to Paris first, stay there for 7 days, travel to Italy (either by train/flight), stay there for 10 days and then return to Paris for another 5 days, before returning to my home country. Since I have a single entry visa, is it possible for me travel from Paris to Italy and then from Italy to Paris?

Comment: Just make sure your flight doesn't pass through a non-Schengen airport.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, it does.

The "single entry" goes for the Schengen region, once inside Schengen you can travel freely within the region, in most cases you won't have to show your visa (or even your passport) when crossing borders between countries within the region.

Comment: I have another question.......

Comment: I have another question. Since I got the Etats Schengen' visa from the Frence Embassy, is it necessary for me to land on France first and exit from France????

Comment: That is not necessary, but you should be prepared to show tickets for your travel onwards to France. For example, it would be perfectly logical to go through immigration at Frankfurt or Amsterdam and to take an intra-Schengen flight to France. If you arrive at Helsinki or Reykiavik, there will be more questions.

Comment: Let's say I enter thru Paris and Exit my journey thru Italy, is it ok??? Do they question me in the Italy airport, why I am getting out from Italy with Schengen visa from France embassy. One more problem is when I submitted fro visa I didn't mention that I am going to travel to Italy and coming back from Italy. This is a last minute change. Dos this affect my exit from Italy?????

Comment: @Gayathri that is perfectly acceptable. You should not be questioned when leaving unless you have overstayed. I've never gotten asked questions on entry or exit with a valid Schengen visa. Also, your plans are allowed to change after you get the visa. I would not worry.

Comment: One more question. One more problem is when I submitted for visa I didn't mention that I am going to travel to Italy and coming back from Italy. This is a last minute change. Does this affect my travel to Italy and exit from Italy?????

Comment: Not a problem, you are allowed to change your travel plans. The only problem is if you mislead them which in this instance you did not. Unless you have a Limited Territorial Visa (which you don't), you are allowed to change your plans and visit another Schengen Visa as long as you do not overstay.

Comment: You seem very nervous about this issue. I would not even mention it to the Guard unless they ask you directly about your plans.

Comment: Not nervous. When I browse thru the internet, I read various kind of questions from different passengers. That's why I had some queries.Thanks for all the details and the clarifications......... Thanks once again Rodney.............

Comment: @Gayathri in general, once you're in people don't care where you go as long as you leave again. Maybe the French would wonder if you overstayed and check with the other Schengen countries for an exit registration, but that's all as long as there is one.